# Site promotional idea and a little fun

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Can't stack send a t-shirt or prize to the person that submits the worst contractor/DIY disaster of the month or maybe have a running list for the year?  I would certainly visit site and meta more if the top 5 for the month were rolled up to me.  I have this month's first nominee - [Why is my ceramic tile popping out of the floor?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/105743/why-is-my-ceramic-tile-popping-out-of-the-floor/105746?noredirect=1#comment158948_105746)

Answer (score 7):

Anecdotes are really not what Stack Exchange is set up for. That's a great idea for another site....

Comment: How is it an anecdote?

Comment: "The worst I have seen" is explicitly anecdotal. It fails Real Questions Have Answers. It also fails because you propose no source of funding for the prizes, not even increased site hits. As I say, fine idea for some other site; not SE, by design.

Comment: It would also result in people grabbing pics from various sites frequented by home inspectors and contractors where such things are quite commonly posted.

Comment: ... and which are a better place for this particular idea. For worst-of-worst, there is always the "there, I fixed it" site.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with keshlam in this case, anecdotes/funny stuff aren't usually the best fit for the main site. Maybe good for [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=diy.stackexchange.com), though?

That said, just to put it out there, we certainly have no problem with supporting a community event/contest with an occasional shirt if you agree on one! Other sites do this occasionally. Code Review had an [extensive best-of](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7102/best-of-code-review-2016) "awards show" at the end of the year, and Travel (just to name one example) does [monthly challenges](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4392/april-answerathon-competition) (I linked to an activity challenge but topic challenges are also common).